# add a static editText view as the last child of a expandableListView Android

Tags: android

I have a problem to add dynamically a static EditText, always in the last children position. My adapter uses JSON objects of type. The first time that I expand the  ExpandableListView group's children, can locate the correct position for my EditText, but when I scroll the children in the opposite direction, my EditText continually changes position. This is my Editext layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
 android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
 android:orientation="vertical" 
 android:paddingLeft="10dip"
 android:paddingRight="10dip"
 android:background="@color/lgray">
<RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/feedcell_addcomment" android:paddingLeft="10dip" android:paddingRight="10dip" android:paddingTop="5dip" android:paddingBottom="5dip" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_marginTop="1dip" android:background="@color/mlgray" >


    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

This is my childLayout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:id="@+id/layoutchildren" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:orientation="vertical" android:paddingLeft="10dip" android:paddingRight="10dip" android:background="@color/lgray">
    <RelativeLayout   android:paddingLeft="10dip" android:paddingRight="10dip" android:background="@color/white" android:layout_height="45dip" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_marginBottom="2dip">
        <ImageView android:id="@+id/feedcommentcell_profileimg" android:layout_width="32dip" android:layout_height="32dip" android:layout_centerVertical="true" android:scaleType="fitXY"/>
        <TextView android:id="@+id/feedcommentcell_username" android:textStyle="bold" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:textSize="13sp" android:textColor="@color/black" android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/feedcommentcell_profileimg" android:layout_marginLeft="10dip" android:layout_alignTop="@+id/feedcommentcell_profileimg"/>
        <TextView android:id="@+id/feedcommentcell_comment" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:textSize="11sp" android:textColor="@color/black" android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/feedcommentcell_profileimg" android:layout_marginLeft="10dip" android:layout_below="@+id/feedcommentcell_username"/>
        <TextView android:id="@+id/feedcommentcell_scanhour" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:textSize="10sp" android:textColor="@color/dgray" android:layout_alignParentRight="true" android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/feedcommentcell_username"/>
        </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

this is my getChildView in my adapter

```
 @Override
        public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, boolean isLastChild,View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
        {

            int type=getItemViewType(groupPosition,childPosition);
            View v = convertView;
            LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

            if (v == null)
            {

                switch(type)
                {

                    case TYPE_CHILD:

                        v = vi.inflate(R.layout.feedcommentcell, null);

                        break;

                    case TYPE_EDIT:

                        v = vi.inflate(R.layout.edittextcommentlist, null);
                        break;
                }

            }

            try
            { 
                if(type == TYPE_CHILD)
                {
                    JSONObject o = getChild(groupPosition,childPosition);
                        //JSONObject o = itemsChildren.get(childPosition);
                    if(o!=null)
                    {
                        TextView commentUser=(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.feedcommentcell_username);
                        commentUser.setText(o.getString("username"));

                        String shareMessageId= o.getString("ShareMessageId");
                        o.put("ShareMessageId", shareMessageId);

                        TextView commentText=(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.feedcommentcell_comment);
                        commentText.setText(o.getString("Message"));

                        TextView commentScanHour=(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.feedcommentcell_scanhour);
                        commentScanHour.setText(o.getString("timestamp"));

                        ImageView commentImg=(ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.feedcommentcell_profileimg);
                        String imgurl=o.getString("userimage");
                        if(imgurl!=null && imgurl!="")
                        imageLoader.DisplayImage(imgurl, context, commentImg);

                    }

                }
                else if(type==TYPE_EDIT)
                {
                    //JSONObject o = getChild(groupPosition,childPosition);
                    JSONObject o = itemsChildren.get(childPosition);


                        o.put("edit", "false");
                        v = vi.inflate(R.layout.edittextcommentlist, null);

                    //EditText edit = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.feedcell_edittxt);


                }




            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {}


            return v;
        }
```

And these are the others overrides methods. I don't show you getGroupView and his layout because works properly..

```
    @Override
         public JSONObject getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
                return itemsChildren.get(childPosition);
            }

        @Override
        public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
                return childPosition;
            }

        @Override
        public boolean areAllItemsEnabled()
        {
            return true;
        }
        @Override
        public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {

            return itemsChildren.size();
        }

        @Override
        public JSONObject getGroup(int groupPosition) {
            return itemsGroup.get(groupPosition);
        }

        @Override
        public int getGroupCount() {
            return itemsGroup.size();
        }

        @Override
        public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
            return groupPosition;
        }
        @Override
        public boolean hasStableIds() {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isChildSelectable(int arg0, int arg1) {
            return true;
        }

        public boolean isTextView(int groupPosition,int childPosition)
        {
            JSONObject jo=new JSONObject();
            jo = getChild(groupPosition,childPosition);
            boolean result =false;
            try
            {
                String isEdit=jo.getString("edit");
                if(isEdit.equalsIgnoreCase("true"))
                    result=true;

            }
            catch(Exception e){}
            return result;

        }

        public int getItemViewType(int groupPosition,int childPosition) 
        {
            //JSONObject jo=getChild(groupPosition,childPosition);


            if(isTextView(groupPosition,childPosition))
                return TYPE_EDIT;
            else
                return TYPE_CHILD;
        }
```

All seems good, but editText changes the position every time...someone has some solutions?Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem with my `ExpandableList`... The main problem here is with `lastChild` property. You see, on creation, the last child of the group list is the one we think it is, but on scroll opposite, your list is refreshing so next last child is next which you can't see on opposite, or if you go back down, last one you can't see. This is pretty much stupid if you ask me but there is no right solution for this...

Answer (score 0):

Since `isLastChild` does not work properly, you can do the following:

```
@Override
public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, 
      boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
      ...

      if (childPosition == itemsGroup.get(groupPosition).size() - 1) {
           // This gives you confirmation that is the last child in the group
      }
}
```

Comment: I have tried it but it is also not working.
Do you have any another solution?